# How Do I Convert From VSCode Deploy To Azure Pipelines?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I have been following this tutorial to deploy a web app on Azure using LocalGit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-03

Now that I have got everything working I would like to set up a scheduled overnight job to deploy the latest code since it takes 15-20 minutes to deploy even the smallest change from the existing process.

Do I have to set up the whole deployment process again or is there an easy way to convert my LocalGit/VSCode deployments to use Azure Pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly setup an Azure DevOps pipeline to achieve this: [Deploying into Azure App Service using Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline](https://devops.com/deploying-into-azure-app-service-using-azure-devops-ci-cd-pipeline/).

On a holistic view, you will have to perform below steps:

1. Upload your code to ADO repository.
2. Create a **CI** Build pipeline to run your project code on agent machines and, create and save artifacts of it.
3. Create **CD** Release pipeline to deploy executables from your artifact(created in step 2) on Azure.

Comment: This sounds like the answer to the question is "No there isn't an easy way to convert it, you have to create the pipelines from scratch."

Comment: Does the response above help?

Comment: Sort of. I was holding out for a bit in case someone had done an automatic conversion already and was going to answer.

Comment: Ok, if you feel that this answers your question, mark it as answer for the community.

Comment: I just said that I don't feel like it answers the question.